# Question about routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails newbie here.

Can anyone please explain the difference to me between the following lines of code:

```
match '/' => 'posts#index'
```

and

```
match '/' => 'posts#index', :as => 'posts'
```

The reason I'm asking is because when I use the latter code, I cannot create new posts :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter is creating a named route. It creates a helper that you can call from your views, in this case, `posts_path` & `posts_url`.

That being said, I'm not sure how you are able to create new posts with either of those as you are not defining the `posts#new` or `posts#create`. Is there more to your routes file than these? Also, I'm not sure if it's a requirement or not, but you should pass your `:as` option as a symbol, so `:as => :posts`.

For reference, you can run `rake routes` from console and see a list of all the routes that are defined in your application. You'll also see how they are named—that's the column all the way to the right—which you can then append `_path` or `_url` to.